# Hiding the status bar and title bar for a specific time

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I want to hide status and title bar both in the same layout for a specific time. Like for 2 or 3 seconds. To do this, I tried **`Timer`** and as I know, **feature request**( **`requestFeature()`** ) must be called before `SetContentView` and `Super.OnCreate`. So, I wrote this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Hiding Title bar of this activity screen //
                    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                    // Making this activity, full screen //
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 5000);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

But it comes with this following error :

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

I think **Timer** is responsible for the error. Because, when I call **requestFeature()** without `Timer`, the app runs without showing any error or crashing.

> **Is there any way to hide status and title bar for a specific time in the same layout? (Not Intent)**

Comment: Move these calls `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);` below `getWindow().setFlags`

Comment: try removing getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); and write getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: @DeepPatel 
Not working. :(

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

Full Screen

```
 // Full Screen call using DecorView
 private void setFullScreen() {
           getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      }
```

Remove From Full Screen

```
private void removeFromFullScreen() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
  }
```

Now in your `OnCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   final android.os.CountDownTimer Count = new android.os.CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
 @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   if (millisUntilFinished/1000 == 2) {
      setFFullScreen();
    }
   Log.e("TAG",millisUntilFinished/1000+"");
  }
  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
    removeFromFullScreen();
  }
};
Count.start();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

Comment: I notice It's working only for full layout! not working for a specific time. :(

Comment: You want to revert back after some time?

Comment: yes, just for a specific time I want to hide the status and title bar and make the layout full screen.

Comment: You have to use CountDownTimer for the same. Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Hiding Title bar of this activity screen //
                         getSupportActionBar().hide();
                        // Making this activity, full screen //
                        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 5000);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

Replace `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` with `getSupportActionBar().hide();` instead.